# Mongoose multiple nested select

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to put select on a large query using multiple nested selectors for example:

```
 .select('parent.0.item parent.0.item2 other item');
```

however the second item from parent array is never selected and only the first one returns. and suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

found that i had simply to remove the '.0,' and to write it like this:

```
.select('parent.item parent.item2 other item');
```

Answer (score 0):

in Mongoose version 4, you don't need to use select() as shown bellow

```
   yourModel.find({}, 'parent.item parent.item2 other item',
     function (err, docs) {
    });
```

Good luck

Comment: Im making an advanced query and using the populate, query and other conditions, so its easier for me to simply use .select().